# Turborepo React app fails to load Tailwind

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, monorepo, turborepo

I’ve created a monorepo with Turborepo that for now have 1 React Vite App, and tailwind-config package. And my problem for now is that my App is not loading tailwind at all.
Let me try to explain you my project structure and files.

```
root
|
|- packages
|   |- tailwind-config
| 
`- apps
    |- container
```

tailwind-config module contains basic package.json, tailwind.config.js and postcss.config.js files.

tailwind.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: [],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```

postcss.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {}
  }
}
```

Inside my container app I added tailwind-config package as the local devDependency, added Tailwind directives to my index.css.

At the end in container I created  tailwind.config.cjs that looks like:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
const sharedConfig = require("tailwind-config/tailwind.config")

module.exports = {
    ...sharedConfig,
    content: ["./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}", "./public/index.html"]
}
```

And postcss.config.cjs

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
  }
}
```

As I mentioned the problem is that container app is not applying any tailwind classes I provide.

Thank you all for help in advance and hope you have nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the exact location of .jsx/.tsx files in tailwind.config.js file
e.g.:

tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
const sharedConfig = require("tailwind-config/tailwind.config")

module.exports = {
    ...sharedConfig,
    content: ["./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}", "./public/index.html", "../apps/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to share tailwind configs is to use [presets](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/presets).

1. Create a `tailwind-presets.js` file in your shared config folder
2. Add all the configuration options you want to use in all projects

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [require("daisyui"), require("@tailwindcss/typography")],
};
```

3. In each project, setup the `tailwind.config.js` to use the preset

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  presets: [require("../../packages/config/tailwind-preset.js")],
};
```

You can override any option individually in each project but this is a fairly straightforward way of sharing the config.